# heroku(Nuxt)からheroku(rails)へのアクセスが404になる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nuxt.js, axios

ローカル(Nuxt)からheroku(rails)への通信は問題なく出来るのですが、
heroku(Nuxt)からaxiosでheroku(rails)へのアクセスしようとすると404エラーになります。
rails側のcorsの設定は問題ないと思われます。
404となっているのはNuxt側のherokuのログで分かりました。
rails側のログでリクエストが届いていないのも確認済みです。
APIテスト用のツールでGETして見たら普通に取れたのでNuxt側の設定だとは思います。
下記にproxyの設定を書いておきます。

```
  proxy: {
    '/rails': {
      target: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/rails': '/'
      }
    }
  },
```

何か分かる方いましたら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
axiosの設定で

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com'
  },
```

としてproxyを外した所、無事リクエストが通りました。
proxyがなくてCORSはどうなるんでしょうか？
疑問は残りますがとりあえず解決したのでご報告です。